# What DDR is this memory?

Tags: memory

I need to replace a memory DIMM for someone. I am not near the computer and I am not sure what was the DIMM type.

I remember it was `Samsung 1Rx8 6400 666` - I am pretty sure it is a DDR2 ,but can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a single-sided DDR2 module running at 666MHz.